# Unable to remove all children from the XML document (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Unable to remove all children from the XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <routes>
      <route name="admin" />
      <!---->
      <route name="blog" bla bla/>
      <route name="blog" bla bla/>
      <route name="blog" bla bla/>
    </routes>
```

$xml = simplexml_load_file('routes.xml');

`$dom_sxe = dom_import_simplexml($xml);
    $dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom_sxe = $dom->importNode($dom_sxe, true);
    $dom_sxe = $dom->appendChild($dom_sxe);


    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('route') as $route)
    {
        if($route->getAttribute('name') === 'blog')
        {

            $route->parentNode->removeChild($route);
            echo $route->getAttribute('name');
        }
    }

    echo $dom->saveXML();`

removes only 2 elements with the attribute **blog**

Comment: Why are you creating a `SimpleXML` object and two `DOM` objects? Does this not come to the same thing as `$dom = new \DOMDocument(); $dom->load('routes.xml')`?

Comment: in that you are right, what about the question about the removal of a child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are modifying the document while looping through it - a bit like modifying an array in the middle of a `foreach` loop.

Note that [`$dom->getElementsByTagName` "returns a new instance of class `DOMNodeList`"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) not just an array. So as the loop goes round it is retrieving the elements as it goes; removing one will mess up its assumptions about what exists.

One solution to this is to copy the entire list of matches into a plain array before you loop over it. There is a built-in function [`iterator_to_array()`](https://www.php.net/iterator_to_array) which will do just that for you all in one go - basically, it runs a `foreach` over the iterable object, and collects the values into an array.

So the simplest (though not necessarily most readable etc) solution is to change this line:

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('route') as $route)
```

to this:

```
foreach (iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName('route')) as $route)
```

[Here's a live demo of the fixed code.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kV7aY6)