# foreach ends before getting through all elements in SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, foreach, simplexml

I loop over a big xml document, and i need to remove some nodes. Unfortunately my foreach breaks after first removing. How is that?

```
$ids = [1, 2];

$data=<<<DNS_TXT
<feed xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<entry><g:id>1</g:id><description>Desc 1</description></entry>
<entry><g:id>2</g:id><description>Desc 2</description></entry>
<entry><g:id>3</g:id><description>Desc 3</description></entry>
<entry><g:id>4</g:id><description>Desc 4</description></entry>
<entry><g:id>5</g:id><description>Desc 5</description></entry>
</feed>
DNS_TXT;

$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

$i = 0;

foreach($doc->entry as $entry)
{
    $i++;

    $dom = $entry->children('http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');

    if(!in_array($dom->id, $ids)) {
        $dom = dom_import_simplexml($entry);
        $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
    }
}

echo $i;
```

Result is 3 instead of 5...

Of course i can do that:

```
/.../

$toRemove = array();
foreach($doc->entry as $entry)
{
    $dom = $entry->children('http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');

    if(!in_array($dom->id, $ids)) {
        $dom = dom_import_simplexml($entry);
        $toRemove[] = $dom;
    }
}

foreach ($toRemove as $dom) {
    $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
}

/.../
```

But why in first case foreach ends?

Comment: What this statement did `$dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);` inside loop???

Comment: `$dom->parentNode` is 'feed' element, so this code removes node that loop is working on

Comment: when you to the parentNode it deletes all the childs so fooreach stops.

Comment: Nope. It deletes only one child and `echo $doc->asXml();` confirmes it - only third node is deleted and 1, 2, 4 and 5 are steel present

Comment: I'm not sure know the structure of simplexml object, but can suppose that when you remove current element, iterator cannot find next, and  break loop

Comment: If use index as in my answer but in ascending order, loop kills every 2nd as with usual array

Comment: This is effectively the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/q/18418991/157957 although that one uses DOM's `->getElementsByTagName` and you're using` SimpleXML's `->children`. The problem is the same - you are modifying the source of a dynamic iterator during iteration, causing it to access data that's no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

In such ways it's better to loop from maximum index to lowest. So it works:

```
$entries = $doc->entry;
for($i = count($entries)-1; $i >= 0; $i--)
{
    $entry = $entries[$i];
    $dom = $entry->children('http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');
    if(!in_array($dom->id, $ids)) {
        unset($doc->entry[$i]);
     }
```

Comment: you changed in the loop but describe only about to start from maximum. what problem actually in the code of OP?